# How can I check if the display is selected?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'd like to check if an LWJGL `Display` is selected or not, i.e. if it is in the foreground.

Is there a `Display.isInForeground()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Display#isActive`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#isActive%28%29)

> Returns:
>       true if window is active, that is, the foreground display of the operating system.

Or if you are using LWJGL 3 and GLFW the equivalent is [`glfwGetWindowAttrib`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwGetWindowAttrib%28long,%20int%29) with `GLFW_FOCUSED`.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I was having trouble finding the documentation.